# Getting android.os.TransactionTooLargeException when sharing picture with others app

Tags: android, image, transactions, share, large-data

Sometimes the app receives the `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` when sharing the picture with others apps. The code is not passing the picture itself but the URI.

After the first crash, it is possible to repeat the same process many times without the problem.

The error `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` also is not specific in order to determine exactly where the problem is.

Is there any way to further debug this error?
How to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
private void sharePicture() {

    BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) mIvPicture.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DogWalkTracker");
    dir.mkdirs();
    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.msgErrorPicture3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outFile));
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outFile));
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.msgSelectApp)));    
}
```

> 12-29 12:59:21.779 15450-15450/br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackeruser E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 667052)
>           12-29 12:59:21.781 15450-15450/br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackeruser D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>           12-29 12:59:21.786 15450-15450/br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackeruser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackeruser, PID: 15450
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 667052 bytes
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3776)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>                                                                                           Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 667052 bytes
>                                                                                              at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3700)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3768)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: From the stack trace, this feels more like you may have a saved instance state `Bundle` that is too large.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. I tested the app and identified that the error occurs after the  onSaveInstanceState, so I looked to the fragment and notice that I was passing to the fragment the picture and other data, so when the activity finished the problem occured, probably due to android saving the fragment data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the app and identified that the error occurs after the execution of the code I posted and after onSaveInstanceState, so I looked to the fragment that was starting the other apps and notice that I was passing to the fragment the picture and other data.

I just passed to the fragment the image Uri and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I had also similar problem with the same issue. I passed bitmap to fragment using args and then triggering sharing activity from the fragment. And every return to fragment crashed. Fragment tried to recover that bitmap onResume.... my solution was quite easy. Affected fragment was bottom dialog fragment with sharing options, so I solved this situation with naviController.navigateUp() before every onPause. That worked for my situation.